# Non-Uniform Scaling during UV unwrap. What is this?

Tags: uv

I've got a problem while unwrapping UVs. When I'm unwrapping UVs it showing me this message. [image]

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's because your object has been scaled on some axes more than others in object mode.

For example:

[image]

It should be fine, but if you are having problems you could try applying the scale by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>*> Scale* in object mode. This will apply the object mode scale "offsets" to the mesh data, resetting the offsets to 1 without  changing the appearance of the model. Note that this could affect modifiers such as bevel. See [Why are the longer edges being beveled more?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/12288/599)

Comment: Pressing ctrl+A , is it as like freezing transforms ? Actually  i am from Maya.

Comment: @SamirChandraBarma Yes, it is the equivalent of freeze transformations.

Comment: It should be fine? No it's not fine at all. It unwraps my entire model into infinitely narrow lines.

Comment: @AzulShiva Sounds like you have a particularly extreme non-uniform scaling then. Have you tried applying the scale (Ctrl+A)?

Comment: I did. I had to unwrap every face at a time.

Comment: @Azul Wait, so scale is at 1,1,1 and it still shows the 'non-uniform scale' message? That's odd..

Comment: Yes. And when I try to unwrap it, at first I thought it didn't. But then I realized it unwrapped all the faces it into an infinitely thin line. I'm guessing something went wrong there with the new blender version...

Comment: @Azul I don't suppose you could upload the file?

Comment: I already unwrapped every face by hand. So I resetted the unwrap with "U" -> "Reset" to get my Unwrap to where it was at the time of the incident, but it unwrapped it just normally. Maybe I should have tried resetting the UV when I got into problems.