# Apply scale when adding UV texture, why? why not?

Tags: texturing, uv, blender-internal-render-engine

should i apply scale when adding a UV texture to a mesh?

If i don't, will the distortion of my uv texture be the only consequence of not doing so?

Thank you!

Comment: The [one reason](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation), [another one](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14524/non-uniform-scaling-during-uv-unwrap-what-is-this) that you have already mentioned