# Mesh interferes with the texture of a plane

Tags: mesh, texturing

So I have a simple scene in blender, there is a track situaded in a grass field. However it seems that the road somehow inteferes with the plane. If I (re)move the track it solves the problem. The same happens with a little car I have that isn't shown. The grass texture is a seamless grass texture 1024x1024 if I recall correctly.

I've chequed the bounding boxes and wireframes and everything seems good.
You can download the .blend file below.

[image: As seen here]

[image]

Comment: please provide more information. For this kind of questions is a lot easier if you provide a blend file for others to look at. You can use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and edit the resulting link into the question.

Comment: It looks like the blend you provided didn't have all the images packed, only the car. Can you try again?

Comment: To include the images into the blend file use "File->External->Pack all into .blend" and save your file again. – cegaton 14 mins ago

Comment: Thanks again to both of you .blend file has been reuploaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by the track interfering... but the texture mapping for the grassy plane is messed up.

First of all, your plane has been scaled in Object mode.

select Select the plane and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> and select **Apply Rotation and Scale**

(More on why you always want to apply your scale [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation) and [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14524/non-uniform-scaling-during-uv-unwrap-what-is-this))

Next: 
Your plane has no UV map, so blender will not know how to map the image.

Go to top view. , enter edit mode select all (<kbd>A</kbd>) press <kbd>U</kbd> to **unwrap** the texture.

[image]

[image]

(note that I changed the number of repeats for illustrations purposes...