# UV map is not straight

Tags: texturing, uv

I tried to unwrap simply cube with bevel. I made a seam and my UV looks like this (vertex are curves):

[image]

It is ok ? Must I use a special addon (Misc) to repair?

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14524/non-uniform-scaling-during-uv-unwrap-what-is-this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right after clicking on Unwrap press F6 and try to change unwrap method.[image]