# UV unwrapping isnt woking

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

Not sure why its not letting me unwrap I have a seam and everything selected. [image]

This also pops when I try to UV unwrap[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Non-Uniform Scaling during UV unwrap. What is this?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14524/non-uniform-scaling-during-uv-unwrap-what-is-this)

Comment: You are using Image editor, switch to UV editor to see the UVs