# Inset in Blender not coming out even

Tags: modeling, mesh

I seem to have screwed up something that allows you to inset evenly, I think I have tried every combination of settings in inset and pivot center and even is far from even.  I tried uninstalling and re installing blender 2.71 and get the same result.  The image attached is a simple default cube that I tried to inset evenly.  I have also attached the blend file link  help??

[image: inset uneven]

[Blend file here.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/n88qbsmko5l1fbk/inset_not_even.blend)

Comment: You need to 'Apply Scale'. See this question: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation

Comment: Thank you so much Ray, I tell folks to remember to apply scale all the time, but hadn't thought to check that the default cube had scale applied.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/12288/599

Answer (score 13):

Your **insets are distorted based on object scale**. To fix this, you will need to apply your object's scale(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>>*Scale*).