# How to inset group of faces

Tags: modeling

Coming from 3ds Max I was wondering if it's possible to inset a group of faces. The result I would like to achieve (using 3ds Max):

[image]

This is the result I get using the inset tool in Blender:

[image]

Comment: Apply the scale to your object https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14868/inset-in-blender-not-coming-out-even

Comment: Thanks, almost there. This fixes the dimensions of the new faces, but they are still disconnected at the corners.

Comment: You have duplicate geometry and zero sized faces. Cleanup your mesh by removing doubles before insetting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments first I had to apply the scale to the object (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>> *Scale*) and then remove doubles (<kbd>W</kbd>> *Remove Doubles*) for the inset to work as expected.

Comment: thats because there where non selected zero faces that result in splits. You can see the points of that faces in your image

Answer (score 6):

Once you activate the [Inset tool](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/duplicating/inset.html?highlight=inset)  Disable "individual"

[image]

Comment: I messed up the geometry somehow so I had duplicated vertices/faces. Otherwise this would have worked.