# How to scale an extrusion from a rectangular plane equally along all four sides?

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to create a very basic shape in the image of a beveled mirror. To do this, I create a plane, extrude from the plane, and then scale the extrusion. However, the beveled edge is deeper on the shorter sides than the longer sides. Dividing the plane into two faces doesn't seem to help. Any ideas on how to create an evenly-sized beveled edge?

[image]

Comment: Dissolve the extrusion and bevel the top plane instead. Scaling will never be the same for the sides of that plane unless you scale by X and Y axes separately. If beveling gives the same result then see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/12288/why-are-the-longer-edges-being-beveled-more

Comment: I think it would be easier to start with the bigger plane and then inset (i key)

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation-to-an-objects-data and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14868/inset-in-blender-not-coming-out-even

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scaling works relative to every single axis.
X is 200cm, 75 percent of that is 50cm smaller than before.
Y is 100cm, 75 percent of that is only 25cm smaller.

Use inset (press 'i') instead - it works with a fixed offset - and move the new face after that.