# how can i inset equally?

Tags: modeling

[image]
I've read the other inset thread but it didn't help me. I'd like to inset the face proportionally, so without distortion. The result I'd like to have: 
[image]

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14868/inset-in-blender-not-coming-out-even/14869?r=SearchResults#14869

Comment: Yup, ctrl+A --> *Apply menu pops* --> *click on scale* worked.