# Edge bevel only bevels over one face, rather than both

Tags: bevel

When I try to bevel this edge:

[image]

I get this issue here:

[image]

I have tried removing doubles (merge by distance) as suggested in the post [Some edges on model won't Bevel](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24478/some-edges-on-model-wont-bevel) and didn't work.

Here's what the face looks like:

[image]

I am also wanting to bevel the edge that joins onto it at the corner:

[image]

To which I get a very wonky result:

[image]

Comment: Have you applied the scale (Ctrl-A > Scale) to the object in Object mode? Also check for duplicate vertices with M > Merge by Distance in Edit mode with All selected. If that doesn't help please share your blend file via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions on the page.

Comment: @JohnEason An unapplied scale could result in uneven width of the bevel, but it's not causing it to move just in one direction as shown in the second image (or only if it was scaled to 0 in that direction, which the model obviously is not).

Comment: Before you bevel delete non-manifold faces or Blender doesn't know what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The face you have selected in this screenshot is flipped. If you enable the *Face Orientation* in the viewport overlays it will show up in red in *Solid* mode, while the others are blue. Select it and hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to recalculate the normals. Or this is the only one that's blue and all others are flipped. Best would be, you select all with <kbd>A</kbd> and then you recalculate the normals to make sure there are no other incorrect faces.

[image]