# Blender 2.74 loop tools make circle disappear

Tags: modeling, mesh, vertices, edges

I have the loop tools addon enabled and when I click the circle button with these verts selected, it just disappears. Why is that?

You can see the selected options in the bottom screenshot. It is worth noting that all the verts are flat on the x plane. Locking in X or not does not change the effect.

When I use the `to sphere` operator it squishes the verts on Z and stretches super wide on Y, not making a cirlce.

[image: loop tools error]

EDIT:

here is the blend

[image]

Comment: That's odd.. Is it possible you could upload your .blend?

Comment: how? stack will only let me up pictures. any easy hosts?

Comment: There's [blend-exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/), a host specifically dedicated to this site :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your object has a pretty extreme object scale on it. To get an idea of how extreme, this is what it would look like without it:

[image]

If you apply the scale to the mesh with <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> it then works as expected:

[image]

See [Why are the longer edges being beveled more?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/12288/599) for some more detail. Suffice it to say that loop tools sees the mesh without the object scale, and that tall thin hole is confusing it.

Comment: ah that would do it... I believe I did some object mode scaling ... my bad :) thanks a lot

Comment: I have 2.75 version and Loop tools doesn't appear in W .What can I do?

Comment: Loop tools  in  2.75 version. Click in User preference/ Add ons / Mesh Looptools and refresh.