# objects disappear when rendered

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, objects

I am having a issue when rendering using cycles, objects disappear and black blocks seem to overlay parts of my textures. this seems to happen at various different angles when the camera is moved around the scene.

Screenshots of material and rendered attached.

Any help would be massively appreciated.

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: It will be helpful if you can upload your blend file to a service like http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and embed it in your question so we can look at it.

Comment: Sorry I cant upload to, my blend file is too big

Comment: Then try to cut out anything from the file that is unnecessary to the question and upload that. It will be hard for us to diagnose the problem without it.

Comment: [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=761" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/761/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not quite sure *why* this causes a problem, but this happens because your 'floor' object is scaled to 0 on the 'Z' axis. Selecting the 'floor' and doing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>> *Scale* will 'apply' the scale, which resets the current scale back to 1 but doesn't change the object appearance.

You can see a detailed explanation of the difference between scaling in edit mode vs object mode [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28558/scaling-in-object-and-edit-mode).

Comment: You mean resets to 1?

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem before try the following steps to see if it works
turn off the render view in modifiers. When I turned off my multires modifier it fixed the problem. So after you turn it off just turn it back on and put in a new one