# Why does Undo only sometimes work?

Tags: interface

I can undo most actions, but some (mirror modifiers, some kinds of scaling) cannot be undone. Pressing Ctrl-Z does not reverse them (the actions show up in my undo history, but nothing happens when I press Undo).

I can undo scaling done with the S key, but not scaling done using this menu:

[image: object menu]

Undo works on most other actions, just not these ones.

I know switching between Object and Edit mode can cause problems for Undo history, but I'm staying in Edit mode the whole time.

What makes these actions "special" in that they cannot be undone by normal means?

Comment: O person with greater knowledge, please feel free to correct my deranged ramblings. When one writes a tool (an _operator_) in Blender, one has to explicitly state that it can be undone. The default behaviour is not to be undoable. That may explain some things. However I think that you are dealing with some bug. I belive that both of the actions you describe should be undoable. Does this happen all the time or only with a (set of) .blend(s)? If so, is it repeatable?

Comment: Adding modifier won't be undone from Edit mode because this is action with object, not with mesh (and when you are in Edit mode you're editing mesh). Could you clarify what is "Scaling using the Object menu" ? If you mean **Object** menu in the bottom 3D View, it won't appear in Edit mode.

Comment: Edited. I'm not sure what to call that menu.

Comment: Editing values from that menu is the same as editing them from Object mode; that data isn't applied to mesh rather than only stored as a property of the whole object, read the [dfiference between that](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28558/scaling-in-object-and-edit-mode). So overall you face differences between what you can undo in Object mode and what - in Edit mode.

Comment: Well... sometimes you just have to sleep, ya know?

Comment: Hey, thanks for this - you led me to examine, and thereby inadvertently shed light on the cause of one of my custom shortcuts not being undo-able. I have M+MMB set to merge verts at center, M+LMB merge verts at first, and M+RMB merge verts at last - so M is the modifier key in this case... however I also have M set as a shortcut to Mark Seams. From a performance standpoint there is no conflict, however when it comes to undo functionality it seems to be confusing the Undo History, so any time I merge verts using this keyboard shortcut I can't undo it. I may need to rethink this key mapping. thx