# Viewing camera shows distorted geometry

Tags: 3d-view, camera

I am modeling a building in blender and I have this strange problem with my viewing camera. The geometry seems like it has been scaled down for the Y axis. I measured a 2 vertices relative to a point and they have the same distance, but in the view, vertex on the X axis seems like it is farther than the one in the Y axis.

[image]

I definitely accidently changed something but I don't know what. Here is my [blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xMtjDFPuCaUVKYA1GXMZPycJ9o1QAyM7/view?usp=sharing). Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: The X/Y scales are different in object mode.

Comment: related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28558/scaling-in-object-and-edit-mode

Comment: @lemon This solved my problem. If you want, you can publish an answer and I shall accept it.

Comment: Good, I will use the previous answer above and indicate that your question is a duplicate of this former one.