# Why does the face look weird after inset and shade smooth?

Tags: modeling

i am trying my first thing without a tutorial. I am beginner. Im making this stove and i want to add a little bump on the side. I inset this face, then inset again and raised it a little. After I shade smooth, the rest of the face ends up looking weird. I would appreciate a lesson :)

[image]

Pictures:

[image: edit mode]
[image: object mode]

Answer (score 2):

You need to apply the scale to that object in <kbd>Object</kbd> mode. Press the <kbd>N</kbd> key which will bring up the R/H properties bar and then click the <kbd>Item</kbd> tab (arrowed). You'll see that the <kbd>Scale</kbd> of the object isn't the same in each direction.

[image]

Hilight the object and hit <kbd>Ctrl-A</kbd> which will bring up the <kbd>Apply</kbd> menu. Select <kbd>Scale</kbd> and the scale will change to 1.000 for X, Y and Z and the shading on your object will now be correct.

[image]

This is important both for insetting faces and using the Bevel modifier in this case.

Comment: Ok Great! So it's always a good rule of thumb to apply scale?

Comment: Yes! Read through the answers here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28558/scaling-in-object-and-edit-mode

Comment: Thanks for this reference and answer, I learned something!