# How to move vertices while modeling?

Tags: modeling, objects, vertices, edges, mirror

I used a plane to start to make a character. When I started to convert it into 3d the I can move any of the vertices on the global x or z directions, but I cannot move any of the vertices on the global y axis, even when the Transformation orientation is switched to global.

A copy of the blend file can be found at:

https://www.mediafire.com/?2b7jks1q6dqy1bu

and here is a screenshot illustrating the issue.

[image]

Comment: You could try to use the green arrow (on the right screen) pointing to the right and drag it

Comment: I suspected the reason you cannot move the vertex on the center line was the  mirror modifier active on a mesh, but in this case, you could move the primary vertices (including the ones on the center) but not vertices resulting from the mirror. But why do the axes on your two views not match? In the right view, the y axis (green arrow) is to the rear, and in the front view the y axis is oriented up and down. You may need to edit your post to include a link to a blend file of the mesh.

Comment: Thanks... plese check the blend file i had uploaded it... search my mistake...

Comment: @AdityaRahul, I found that the reasons the axes do not match is that the transformation orientation on the "front ortho" view (on the left) is set to local, while the transformation orientation on the "right ortho" view (on the right) is set to global.

Comment: @AdityaRahul, I thought maybe that there was a location transform lock on the y axis, but there is not. I can move any vertex in your original mesh on the x or z axes, but not on the global y. But I also found that although I can add vertices to your character mesh, I cannot add any other primitives to the mesh in edit mode. On the other hand, if I switch to object mode, I can add a new plane object, and in edit mode I can add a vertical loop cut, delete the rightmost vertices, and add a mirror modifier. (Continued)

Comment: (Continued)On this plane I am can move any vertex along any axis, and I can add another primitive.  Apparently, you original plane where you started doing the character has some kind of lock on it, but I haven't seen it before, and can't help you unlock. I'd save a copy of the current file to support a bug report, and start a new object. .

Comment: @brasshat thankyou so much ... for supporting me...

Answer (score 3):

I'm not quite sure how the mesh has got like this, but essentially I think the mesh has been scaled (in object mode, I think) so it has zero thickness (in the object panel the 'z' scale value is '0') which I think is why you can't move anything in edit mode. Any movement is being 'squashed' back to zero.

To fix this you can go to object mode, select the mesh and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>> *Scale*. This 'applies' the scale, resetting the scale values to '0' but leaving the mesh appearance unchanged.

This question may help, though applying scale can be a complex subject:

[Why are the longer edges being beveled more?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/12288/why-are-the-longer-edges-being-beveled-more)

Answer (score 0):

Try to check your dimensions in the properties panel under 'transform'. If it's close to zero you won't be able to see any movement on the Y axis. I increased it and at least Y axis is working fine now.
Hope this helps you.