# Bevel Tool not cutting evenly

Tags: bevel

Does the Bevel Tool only evenly Bevel if the object is a pure cube or square?

My Bevel Tool currently only cuts into one face, at a sort of 5-1 ratio rather than an even spread.

In this example, I want the bevel to 'corner off' the, well, corner. As marked in red.

I'm a newish modeller and it's possible some settings are scrambled or something.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/12288/why-are-the-longer-edges-being-beveled-more/12289#12289 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation-to-an-objects-data/7349#7349 https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=bevel+evenly

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of coincident edges.

If you start with an edge close to the corner, the bevel will be clamped on one side (left and middle, below). If the edge is slid all the way down so you can't see it, the bevel will only happen on one side (right).

[image]

Note, if you're in Face selection mode, and you have face markers switched on, you can see the scrunched face .. it's the dot in the middle of the corner edge.

Solution: Remove doubles (2.79: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>,<kbd>R</kbd>. 2.8: <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> Merge > 'By Distance')