# Bevel edge rounds more on 1 side than another side

Tags: bevel

I am trying to bevel a rectangle edge to make rounded edges but when I bevel, I am rounding more of one side compared to the shorter side of the rectangle. How can I bevel the same amount on both sides for a rectangle.

[image: Bevel example]

Comment: Hello :). You need to apply scale. *Object > Apply > Scale*.

Comment: Mods can mark as duplicate based on the above link.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/12288/why-are-the-longer-edges-being-beveled-more/12289#12289

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should "apply scale".

In object mode <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> then *'scale'*.

[image]